# How to close an activeMidForm and open another?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have a method that I use the open a Mid Child.

Lets say I am on a form called "InventoryAdd" on this form I have a drop down menu. When a user selects a value "-1" from the menu, I want to open another (ie. DepartmentsAdd().) Then after DepartmentAdd open I want to close InventoryAdd form.

this is the code behind the menu on InventoryAdd form

```
private void InputDepartment_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //InputDepartment.ValueMember = "ID";
    int selectedDept = Convert.ToInt32(InputDepartment.SelectedValue);

    if (selectedDept == -1) {
        Form myForm = this.ActiveMdiChild;

        Common.OpenMyForm("Vendors", new string[] { "add" }, new DepartmentsAdd());

        if (myForm != null) {
            myForm.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This method what opens the new Mid form

```
    public static void OpenMyForm(string sectionName, string[] keys, Form myform) {
        //make sure there are no other forms of the ame type open
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms) {
            if (form.GetType() == myform.GetType()) {
                form.Activate();
                return;
            }
        }

        if (Settings._AuthenticationMode == "Thumbprint") {

            var newMDIChild = myform;

            // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
            newMDIChild.MdiParent = AppContext.CurrentContext.MainForm;

            // Display the new form.
            newMDIChild.Show();
        }


        if (Settings._AuthenticationMode == "Single" && UserInfo.Autherized == true) {

            var role = new Roles();

            if (role.hasAccess(sectionName, keys)) {
                var newMDIChild = myform;

                // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
                newMDIChild.MdiParent = AppContext.CurrentContext.MainForm;

                // Display the new form.
                newMDIChild.Show();
            }
            else {
                Common.Alert("You do not have a permissions to perform this action!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code open the Mid form with no issues. However, the "InventoryAdd" form never close. "myForm" is always null to it never close it.

How can I properly close the Mid form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set an event listener for [shown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the newly opened form in the calling context you can have the existing form close itself once its child is opened.

```
Form myForm=new Form();
myForm.shown += closeForm;
...

void closeForm(object sender, EventArgs e){
this.Dispose(); // as long as within the previous           forms context.
}
```

Comment: That did the trick :) thank you so much. I do have one more question, Why are you using `Dispose()` and not `Close()`? is there a benefits of using it? note that both works fine with no issues.

Comment: Close will remove the form but maintain the object to be reopened if accessed if you needed. Dispose removes the object from memory. You could use close if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
myForm.Close();
```

is closing the program try to use

```
myForm.Hide();
```